# iPhone - OpenGL using C++ tutorial/snippet

Tags: c++, iphone, c, opengl-es

Is there any good tutorial or code snippet out there on how to use OpenGL via C/C++ on the iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html

I'm pretty sure you need a bit of Objective-C to create the context and do other initialization stuff. The rest is also usable in C++.

Answer (score 3):

In XCode, go to File > New Project... and choose the "OpenGL ES Application" template.  That creates a project with great example code for setting up an OpenGL context and drawing into it with the usual C functions.  Plus some other neat tricks like loading a UIImage into an OpenGL texture.

Comment: the openGL api is mercifly in C for the iphone.

note that you might have a problem putting c++ in one of those files in that template. it might be set up to work only with c, not c++. if it is, right click on the file in the solution explorer in xcode, 
go Get Info->General tab->File Type and set it to 'sourcecode.cpp.objcpp'

Comment: @matt: or simply rename the cpp-file-extension to .mm

Answer (score 1):

The author of "Beginning iPhone Development" has a number of iPhone OpenGL tutorials on his [blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html).  Additionally, he provides a template project for OpenGL in his first tutorial.  Some Objective-C is required to work with OpenGL on the iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

This guy from Stanford shows step by step how-to make a game using C++ and Open GL. It's free on iTunes U. Here is the [link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/designing-multimedia-ios-apps/id473757255?i=109504506)

I learned so much from it. I actually made my first game after watching this video. He also teaches about the structure.

If you are looking for more in depth learning,  you can also check out [this link (which is not free)](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-5-training/Building-and-Monetizing-Game-Apps-for-iOS/82407-2C.html?srchtrk=index:2%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aobjective%20c%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2). I believe the first video will put you on the right track though :)

Comment: Where does that link mention c/c++ ??