# OpenGL ES on the iPhone with C++?

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to run some working C++ OpenGL code on the iPhone. So far, I managed to run an Objective-C/OpenGL ES example on the iPhone, and some Objective-C->plain C++ file ("hello world" output to the console).

But I can't any C++ OpenGL code. The exact problem is including the OpenGL library in the C++ file:

If I use the imports for Objective-C:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
```

it will say at all gl* calls "Use of undeclared identifier 'gl*'".

If I use the imports I use in only C++:

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

It says OpenGL/OpenGL.h file not found (which I had expected, since OpenGL is full OpenGL library, not OpenGL ES).

So how do I use this C++ file?

Already searched:

http://www.hackint0sh.org/iphone-developer-exchange-9/iphone-sdk-can-i-use-c-opengl-38638.htm

[iPhone - OpenGL using C++ tutorial/snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451548/iphone-opengl-using-c-tutorial-snippet)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW1

But I don't find how to use the C++ file.

Comment: I suppose, in the first case you forgot to link an appropriate library while compiling. In the second case the included file just doesn't exist.

Comment: The libraries from the first case work when the file is objective-c. The included files from the second case don't exist only when the project is for iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:-

```
#include <OpenGLES/AEGL.h>
```

Comment: It says `file not found`